# how to Pass model data to Javascript in django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm creating a site where I have to show different markers on the map like [this](https://waqi.info/). I have saved the latitude, longitude, city_name and country_name in the model called `City` now what I want is to access this model data in Javascript to add markers.
I have tried converting the Python data to JSON but i couldn't because I have no idea how to do this. I have looked for the solutions but they all are very confusing as I have no idea of converting Python data to JSON and serializers.

This is the code I have:

```js
{% extends "map/base.html"%}

{% block content%}

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
var map;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 30.3753, lng: 69.3451},
        zoom: 6
    });                 
        //declare marker call it 'i'
        var marker, i;
        //declare infowindow
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        //add marker to each locations

        var locations = {{marker}}

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map,
                icon: locations[i][3]
        });
        //click function to marker, pops up infowindow
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
            })(marker, i));
        }
    } //initmap end
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

{% endblock%}
```

```html
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import City
import json
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
# Create your views here.

def map(request):
    marker = City.objects.all()
    for item in marker:
        print(item)
        item = model_to_dict(item)
    marker = json.dumps(marker)
    context_dict['marker']= marker
    context = {
        'marker': context_dict,
    }
    return render (request, "map/index.html", context)
```

```html
from django.db import models

class City(models.Model):
    
    country = models.CharField("Country",max_length=100, blank=False)
    city = models.CharField("City",max_length=100, blank=False)
    lan = models.DecimalField("Latitude",max_digits=15, decimal_places=8, blank=False)
    lng = models.DecimalField("Longitude",max_digits=15, decimal_places=8, blank=False)
  
    def __str__(self):
        return self.city +"-"+ self.country

    class Meta:
        # order of drop-down list items
        ordering = ('country',)
        # plural form in admin view
        verbose_name_plural = 'cities'
```

Comment: You typically serialize it, with a serializer, and then pass a `JsonResponse` instead of a HTML one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem after converting it to JSON how to access it in js?

Comment: You should use Ajax (Asynchronous JS request) to your django endpoint, which should return json response data.

Comment: marker = City.objects.all()                                                                                   
marker = JsonResponse(marker,safe=False)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Now its giving this error "Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable"

Comment: You need to build javascript variable using template rendering. I would build json object like string in python view.Like this:  json_obj_str = "{'a':'b', 'c':'d'}". Then I would render this string as javascript variable in template.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I would make arrays in array containing your lan and lng. Then I would render this var as javascript variable in template.

```
def map(request):
    marker = City.objects.all()
    array_of_array = []
    for item in marker:
        array_of_array.append([item.lan,item,lng])
    return render (request, "map/index.html", {'marker': str(array_of_array)})
```

Comment: so i dont need to convert my data to JSON to access it in js?

Comment: No in this case treat your javascript as html code, just render this javascript var with needed datatype, I would go with arrays in array. You would need json object during ajax requests.

Comment: [ [ ' P a k i s t a n ' , ' F s d ' , D e c i m a l ( ' 3 1 . 4 1 2 5 7 3 4 0 ' ) , D e c i m a l ( ' 7 3 . 1 1 4 5 6 0 4 0 ' ) ] , [ ' P a k i s t a n ' , ' L h r ' , D e c i m a l ( ' 3 1 . 4 4 6 1 5 9 4 0 ' ) , D e c i m a l ( ' 7 4 . 2 8 0 7 5 8 8 0 ' ) ] ] this is what im getting .Now,how to access the specific data from this array in js